# Capturing by Reference vs. Moving, Lambdas

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda

I am confused about the difference between passing a variable by reference into a lambda (1) versus moving it into the lambda (2) in the capture list. Both yield the same result, but I'm not sure what the implications of using either/or is under the hood (and hence, what is best practice?).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
using std::cout;
using std::make_unique;


int main() {    
    auto p = make_unique<int>(500);     
    auto lambda = [&p]() {
        cout << "Inside the lambda -- value = " << *p << '\n';
    };

    lambda();
}
```

Alternatively, one can replace the lambda above with the one below using std::move.

```
    auto lambda = [ptr = std::move(p)]() {
        cout << "Inside the lambda -- value = " << *ptr << '\n';
    };
```

Which one is preferred and what exactly is std::move doing in this case? Is it deleting the pointer p and transferring its "data" to ptr?

Thanks!

Comment: Neither of the shown examples pass any variable into either lamba. The lamba functions have no parameters. What they do show is lambdas ***capturing*** variables, by value or reference. This is something that's fundamentally different than passing something as a parameter to a lambda, and you should focus, first, on understanding the difference.

Comment: Thanks, that's an important distinction. Passing would happen in the parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you capture by reference, then the lambda's captured `ptr` just refers to p, so changes to p will be reflected when you call `lambda()`.  An easy way to see this is to reassign p just before you run lambda.  E.g.

```
p.reset(new int(100));
lambda();
```

When capturing by reference, lambda will now print 100.  With a move capture, the lambda still prints 500, since it is holding onto the original unique_ptr, which won't be deleted until `lambda` goes out of scope.

Conversely, with a move capture, you've moved the pointer out of `p`, so it's invalid to dereference `p` until you assign a new value to `p`.  If you try to dereference p after the lambda has been created, you'll probably see a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, they are not the same.

In order to practically understand the differences and the implications, we can do an analogy with a `struct`.

---

#### Lambda with reference

The following lambda:

```
 auto lambda = [&p]() {
   cout << "Inside the lambda -- value = " << *p << '\n';
 };
```

could be *implemented* with the following `struct`:

```
struct __lambda_reference {
  __lambda_reference(std::unique_ptr<int>& p_ref): p(p_ref) {}

  void operator()() const {
    std::cout << "Inside the lambda -- value = " << *(this->p) << '\n';
  }

 private:
   std::unique_ptr<int>& p;
};

auto lambda = __lambda_reference(p);
```

So when you *construct* the lambda, a **reference** to the `std::unique_ptr` is stored inside the lambda itself. That might lead to big implications: the referred object (`p`) is not owned by the lambda.

In this case, for instance, you have to care about the liveness of `p` outside the lambda in order to avoid problems such as *dangling reference*.

For example:

```
int main() {    
  auto p = make_unique<int>(500);     
  auto lambda = [&p]() {
    cout << "Inside the lambda -- value = " << *p << '\n';
  };

  p.reset();  //  p has been reset here!!! The pointer is NULL!

  lambda();  // Undefined Behaviour here. Because lambda will call *p inside which is null!
}
```

---

#### Lambda with move

The following lambda:

```
 auto lambda = [ptr = std::move(p)]() {
   cout << "Inside the lambda -- value = " << *ptr << '\n';
 };
```

could be *implemented* with the following `struct`:

```
struct __lambda_move {
  __lambda_reference(std::unique_ptr<int> p): ptr(p) {}

  void operator()() const {
    std::cout << "Inside the lambda -- value = " << *(this->ptr) << '\n';
  }

 private:
   std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
};

auto lambda = __lambda_move(std::move(p));
```

As you can see, the scenario is now completely different. The "internal" variable (`ptr`) is not a reference anymore.

In this case, the lambda will *take the ownership* of the pointer during its construction. Following the logic behind `std::move` is like the lambda *"steals"* the resource.

Therefore, after lambda's construction, there is no more correlation between `p` (local variable of `main`) and `ptr` (the internal variable of lambda). They are two different separate objects.

In practice:

```
int main() {    
  auto p = make_unique<int>(500);     
  auto lambda = [ptr = std::move(p)]() {
    cout << "Inside the lambda -- value = " << *ptr << '\n';
  };

  // now p (the local variable of main) is null because lambda stole it!

  assert(p == nullptr); // !!!!   

  // here you can even reassign p. The object inside lambda is another object.

  lambda();  
}
```

---

> and hence, what is best practice?

As always, it depends.

Generally, you should avoid creating dangerous dependencies with references.
Therefore, just for the scope of this snippet, I would suggest the second option (move the pointer inside the lambda).

However, there are some cases, where you do not want your lambda steals the resource because you probably need that after in your function.